# Restler: Internal actions

Tags: php, rest, action, internal, restler

Is there a way to perform REST actions in the middle of executing an action? For example, if I perform `GET /index.php/book/1` I might receive the following:

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "This is a book.",
    "owner_id" : 4
}]
```

But what I'd like to do is before returning the above object, perform a `GET /index.php/user/4` so the end result is:

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "This is a book.",
    "owner" : {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "John Smith",
        "age" : 40
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is even simple way of doing this with Restler by internally calling another api method directly instead of wasting one call to the server

```
class User{
    public function get($id, $includeOwner = true){
        $result = getUserFromDB($id)
        if($includeOwner){
            $result['owner'] = $this->get(getOwnerIdFromDB($id),false);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

HTH